# How to remove the outline when using inset box shadow and Border Radius

Tags: css

So I have a div, which has a `border-radius` and an inset `box-shadow`, however the inset `box-shadow` doesn't seem to extend to the edges of the div, and results in a faint outline of the original div.

Is there a way to make the `box-shadow` extend out all the way to cover the entire div?

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px white
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

(The browsers I have detected this being the case in are Chrome and IE10 so far)

Comment: Definitely a bug - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=433946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not achieve the same thing with just a plain border and `box-sizing:border-box`?

```css
div {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:10px solid white;
  cursor:pointer;


}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: There will be some difference if that element has contents inside.

Comment: True, depends on the effect being required. Pseudo-element works well though.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would work better than the box-shadowing I was originally doing, though the psuedo element would also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `border` instead of that `box-shadow`. But since the `box-shadow` is `inset`, the `border` can't be set to the element, but a `::before` pseudo-element will do the trick:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}
#fixed {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#fixed:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid white;
  background-color: red;
}
#problem{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">Foo bar baz</div>
<div id="problem">Foo bar baz</div>
```