# Ghost line when adding box-shadow to a div with background-image and circular shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I want to insert an image with a box-shadow that "opens" when you hover over with the mouse. The problem is that a ghost border is appearing and I am not sure how I can deal with it.

I tried setting a border with black color, also to set the background-color of the div containing the image to black, but it's not helping.
Is there another approach I could take here?

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}

#imageShadow {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 140px rgb(0, 0, 0) inset;
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
    background-image: url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/866/butterfly-1-1535829.jpg');
}


#imageShadow:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0) inset;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">  
</head>

<body>
<div id='imageShadow'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

After seeing some comments, I will add an image of what I can see. Is that a "me" problem and has nothing to do with the solution itself?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tested your snippet in Firefox and Chromium on a Mac, and I can't see what you are talking about.

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383957/how-to-remove-the-outline-when-using-inset-box-shadow-and-border-radius

Comment: @Chalas unfortunately no, since I adding the border reduces the image size, not achieving the effect that I want (as per my snippet above). Thank you though

Comment: Check my blogpost: https://hyneks.cz/blog/circular-reveal-animation-simple-and-dirty-way/. It might not be the simplest solution (few more elements, some z-indexes) and currently works just for square images, but I am sure it can be adjusted for any image format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different idea using `mask` instead of `box-shadow`

```css
#imageShadow {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(#000 50%, #0000 72%) 50%/40% 40% no-repeat;
  transition: 1s;
  background-image: url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/866/butterfly-1-1535829.jpg');
}

#imageShadow:hover {
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, black,blue);
}
```

```html
<div id='imageShadow'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN, a box-shadow automatically picks the border-radius of the element itself. If a border-radius is specified on the element with a box shadow, the box shadow takes on the same rounded corners. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

So i suggest a patch in the form of "outline + offset":

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}

#imageShadow {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    outline:10px solid black;
    outline-offset:-5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 140px rgb(0, 0, 0) inset;
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
    background-image: url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/866/butterfly-1-1535829.jpg');
}


#imageShadow:hover {
    outline:10px solid black;
    outline-offset:-5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0) inset;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">  
</head>

<body>
<div id='imageShadow'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Althougth I went with Temani solution due to its simplicity, I applaud you for posting this. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve by using borders and changing the background color.  It's great to have different solutions for the same problem.